# Finding the length of keys of dictionary based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
input_dict = {'ab':12, 'cd':4, 'ef':1, 'gh':8, 'kl':9}
out_dict = 2
```

Is there any way to find the length of keys of the dictionary, if the values in dictionary are greater than 2 and less than 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
In [61]: len([v for v in d.values() if 2 < v < 9])
Out[61]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find number of items in dictionary where value is `2 < v < 9`:

```py
input_dict = {"ab": 12, "cd": 4, "ef": 1, "gh": 8, "kl": 9}

out = sum(2 < v < 9 for v in input_dict.values())
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just returning the relevant lengths:

```
[len(k) for k, v in input_dict.items() if 2 < v < 9]
```

Returns:

```
[2, 2]
```